# Left And RIght Arrow Key Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I am using the code below to detect whether the left and right arrow key is being pressed. I only use this to send the user to the next or prev page. So far everything works perfectly fine, I have a textarea and input field on my page, and when the left and right arrow key is being pressed, it triggers the function as well which I do not want. How do I fix this?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
                if (e.keyCode == 37) { 

                   return false;
                }else if(e.keyCode == 39){


                   return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){

    if(!($(e.target).is('textarea') || $(e.target).is('input')))
     {
       if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
           return false;
       }else if(e.keyCode == 39){ 
           return false;
       }
     }

 });
```

Or you can use `e.stopPropagation` on that `textarea` and `input` boxes too.

Comment: @user3135626 Glad to help.! consider it accepted if this answer satisfied your need. :)